# jQuery toggle function on the same class placed in two different tabs are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabbed layout with some fields. There are four tabs of which two have the same fields (Like advanced search) except that it pulls data from two different sources. I have a multiple select box which I require to toggle display on button click. The jQuery works fine on one tab but it wouldn't work when I switch tabs.

```
$('button#toggle-select').click(function(){
$('.select-multiple').toggle();
});
```

I would require this toggle to work across all tabs

Answer (score 1):

Just add one class for show and hide.

```js
$('#toggleselect').on('click',function(){
$('.select-multiple').each(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
})

})
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="button" class="myButton" value="Advance Search" id="toggleselect">
<div class="form-group select-multiple">
<select id="sel1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group select-multiple hide">
<select  id="sel2">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option> 
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers thanks for the solution. I have fixed it already as the template gets rendered by a php function. So it requires key for each tab created. i added the key to id and it now works fine :)

Comment: Oh, that's wonderful...!

Answer (score 0):

`$('button#toggle-select').live("click",function(){
$('.select-multiple').toggle();
});`

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation for what this code is doing, and how it relates to the question?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc)